# How to group list of lists by sublist

Tags: c#, linq

Input: list of lists of two integers

```
List<List<int>> lists = new List<List<int>>() {
  {1,2},
  {20,21},
  {3,2},
  {21,55}
};
```

output: list of lists of two integers which have the same first **OR** second integer value

```
{
  {{1,2}, {3,2}}, 
  {{20,21}, {21,55}}
}
```

Comment: [ask], and [mre] would have been nice. _"list of lists of two integers"_? Is those 2 integer a Tuple? and array? A keypair? An object with 2 properties? Do you have the initilisation of a smallest sample. And the expected result. Do you want to group in place in the nested nested . or flattern?

Comment: Please, provide an *example* of both *input* and the expected *result*

Comment: Ok so if the inner element is a list are you sure there is alway 2 element for the group by ? May there be more? may there be less?Or do you need to guard against that

Comment: What is the expected answer for `{{1, 2}, {3, 2}, {2, 5}}`, please?

Comment: the same {{1, 2}, {3, 2}, {2, 5}}

Comment: Select the first two elements of inner list using Take(2), and compare them with Any()/Contains().

Comment: Does this answer your question? [writing a custom comparer for linq groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37733773/writing-a-custom-comparer-for-linq-groupby)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://dotnetfiddle.net/Udb15e
As stated in [writing a custom comparer for linq groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37733773/), When writing your own IEqualityComparer, you have to implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.
But `GetHashCode` will be called first and if they are different `Equals` will not be called.
So we need to force `GetHashCode`  to a constant.

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231845/c-sharp-linq-group-by-on-multiple-columns
class ListFirstTwoComparer : IEqualityComparer<List<int>>
{
    public bool Equals(List<int> a, List<int> b)
    {
        var a2 = a.Take(2);
        var b2 = b.Take(2);

        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092930/check-if-listt-contains-any-of-another-list
        return  a2.Any(x => b2.Any(y => y == x));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(List<int> input)
    {
        return 0;       
    }
}

var result = lists.GroupBy(p => p, new ListFirstTwoComparer());
```

Result :

```
[
    {    
        {1,2},
        {1,2},
        {3,2}        
    },
    {        
        {20,21},
        {21,22}        
    }
]
```